# PreparedStatement retaining session settings in JNDI

Tags: oracle, connection, weblogic, prepared-statement, roles

I am trying to create a connection factory. While fetching connections, I am setting session with a few Oracle roles. Below is the pseudocode:

```
SET ROLE NONE;
if(condition is met by user)
{
SET ROLE ABC;
}
return connection;
```

This is working all fine in Tomcat, and while using Statement in WebLogic but when I am firing PreapredStements on a WebLogic server, it is retaining roles of the previous connection.

Can someone help me in this? Why is there a difference in execution of Statement and PreparedStatement when when they are binded to the same connection.

To debug this, I created 150 connections for 2 different users and fired a statement and a prepared statement in for all the connections while closing both before next execution.

If the users are usr1 and usr2 , I fired 50 statements and 50 preparedstatements for 50 connections from usr1.Every execution was as per the roles assigned to that user. Then I fired 50 statements from usr2, in this case all 50 statements worked fine but 50 preparedstatements were fored with settings of usr1 and not usr2.

Note: I am closing all connections properly. I am printing hashcodes of preparedstatements and they are all unique.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case someone else gets stuck on the same issue in future.

WebLogic has a caching mechanism for prepared statements and callable statements. When I went to the admin panel and browsed to advanced connection  pool settings for JNDI, I turned statement cache to 0 and everything was fine after that.